# "que de costumbre" / "than usual", what is this grammatical construction called, or why is "de" used here?

Tags: gramática

I'm reading the book "Harry Potter y la piedra filosofal", and I came across this line:

"Tenían el dormitorio para ellos y la sala común estaba mucho más vacía que de costumbre," which I've translated to, "They had the dormitory to themselves and the common room was much more empty than usual." Why "que DE costumbre"?

Comment: Why would you backtranslate this? The sentence was originally in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"De costumbre" is an idiom that means "usual" or "usually", as listed [in DLE](https://dle.rae.es/costumbre):

> **de costumbre**
> 1. loc. adj. Usual y ordinario. U. t. c. loc. adv.

Here, "loc. adj." means "locución adjetiva", which is an "idiom that functions as an adjective". And "U. t. c. loc. adv." means that it can also be used as an adverb.

This is not a common grammatical construction, but a specific idiom: you cannot replace "costumbre" with a synonym and say "de hábito" for example.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been studying and now realize there are many prepositional phrases and verbs that require specific prepositions, that were causing me confusion, and that I simply have to memorize.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que me llama poderosamente la atención, y me causa auténtica perplejidad, es que traduzcas al español una obra que está escrita originalmente en inglés. La frase de su autora es ligeramente distinta a la que tú escribes. Por eso me pregunto por qué, si **J. K. K. Rolling** escribió

> They had the dormitory to themselves and the common room was far emptier than usual

tú te empeñas en escribir

> They had the dormitory to themselves and the common room was much more empty than usual

Literalmente, es como si cogieras una traducción al inglés de *El ingenioso hidalgo Don Quijote de la Mancha*, y a partir de ella crearas tu propia versión en castellano, obviando la de **Cervantes**.

En cuanto a tu pregunta, la traducción es directamente la que existe en la versión publicada (transcribo la frase completa):

> Tenían el dormitorio para ellos y la sala común estaba mucho más vacía que de costumbre, así que podían elegir los mejores sillones frente al fuego.

En el párrafo se explica directamente: como estaba más vacía de lo habitual (="que de costumbre") tenían mayor posibilidad de elegir el sillón que les convenía.

Answer (score -1):

La pregunta **"que de costumbre"**

La cuestión real se reduce a la forma elegida por el traductor/a para expresar un hábito;

"They had the dormitory to themselves and the common room was much more empty than usual." *y su traducción*

"Tenían el dormitorio para ellos y la sala común estaba mucho más vacía que *de costumbre*".

---

En Español, tenemos para hábitos;

- La forma adj. "*usual*" / adv. "*usualmente*", en Español se emplea como forma que se usa, utiliza o practica frecuentemente. En Inglés, por contra "usual", se suele traducir del Inglés al Español de dos formas, según la persona que traduce, como en Español "*usual*" ó bajo la forma como "*de costumbre*".
- El verbo *Soler*, "used to",  Se emplea normalmente en Español para expresar acciones que ocurren frecuentemente, siempre seguido de un infinitivo, explícito o sobrentendido, normalmente para indicar el carácter habitual de la acción que dicho infinitivo expresa. Habitualmente y según la persona que traduce, lo interpreta como "tener la costumbre de hacer algo" ó "soler hacer algo".
- *Costumbre* "customs", como hábito o tendencia adquirida, se emplea en Español cuando existe una práctica frecuente de un acto que se alarga en el tiempo.

Por tanto el traductor en su interpretación, ha escogido la primera opción "*usual*" y lo ha traducido como "*de costumbre*", aunque cuando se utiliza "de costumbre" en Español, se introducen otros matices y variaciones que cambian un poco el sentido, pues el hábito de las mismas acciones se alarga en el tiempo algo más, como he intentado explicar. Mejor "*y la sala común estaba más vacía de lo usual ó habitual*".